# Shell script: import file

Tags: shell

I've create a separated shell script with functions. For example:

`wsec-curl.sh`:

```
generate_post_data()
{
  cat <<-EOF
  {
    "kind": "Secret",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "$SECRET_ID"
    },
    "stringData": {
    }
  }
EOF
}
```

So, I import it using `. ./wsec-curl.sh`. However, when I perform shell I'm getting this message:

> Can't open ./wsec-curl.sh

**EDIT**

I'm using `#!/usr/bin/env sh`

Comment: The same works perfectly fine for me though :( missing some permissions may be ??

Comment: I'm using `#!/usr/bin/env sh`. Has it nothing to do?

Comment: still it works for me .. :(

Answer (score 0):

This likely means that the file `wsec-curl.sh` is not in the working directory. For testing purposes, do a

```
echo Working directory is: $PWD
ls -l
. ./wsec-curl.sh
```

and verify whether your shell script file is in the directory or not.

UPDATE:

Another possibility would be that you don't have read access to the file, so if the file is there, try a

```
chmod u+r wsec-curl.sh
```

Comment: In this case it would give an "No such file or directory error" i guess

Comment: I think the message depends on the shell. `dash` says, for instance, "....: not found", but the OP did not specify, which shell he was using (`sh` can be pretty anything, depending on the platform), so "can't open" looks like a sensible error message for me. Of course it *could* also mean that read access is missing. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I executed your script in your way, no errors. @sonali pujari, no, it doesn't need to be an executable file.

Is the output all of it?

The possible reason, IMHO, may be you have not the right to read, or the file is not in the current directory

Answer (score -1):

check whether your script has executing rights.

If not " chmod +777 wsec-curl.sh " and give a try.

Comment: You don't need execution rights for sourcing a file.